# AWS Python Serverless with API Gateway Authorizer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have scenario that my backend is deployed by using serverless and having custom auth system on API Gateway on AWS.

First, the request is checked by API Gateway custom authorizer that I have build. If the request is valid, Authorizer adding a request query into my backend. This is how I did it:

```
# new! -- add additional key-value pairs associated with the authenticated principal
# these are made available by APIGW like so: $context.authorizer.<key>
# additional context is cached
context = {
    'user_id': user_id  # $context.authorizer.key -> value
}
```

The drawback if you are using serverless that you cannot mapping context into query string in Integration Request, this is the sample when you are using serverless deployment:

[image: Intgration Request with serverless deployment]

This is the sample if you are using HTTP integration type:

[image: Integration Request with normal deployment]

I have check that my context is cannot be seen or retrieve from my serverless python flask app. I have used this to retrieve all request but cannot see the user_id from authorizer context:

```
print(request.values)
```

This is from CloudWatch, it should be another key value of user_id -> id:

[image]

Is there any idea how to get the context from Authorizer from my lambda flask serverless function ?

**Additional important information !**

I found that lambda proxy integration setting, sent authorizer context as event.
How can I access it by using python flask serverless deployment ?

[image]

Thank You